# Saving LinearRegression (from sklearn.linear_model) coefficients in a list

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm stuck in a problem that should be very simple. I'm running four simple linear regressions (changing only the x variables) and I need to store both de intercept and the scope coefficient in a list, for all regressions.

I thought it would be very easy, but it seems I'm not good at handling lists. The result stores me the same coefficients for all four models in the list.

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
variables = ['Number_of_likes','Number_of_comments','Number_of_followers','Number_of_repplies']
models = [None] * 4


lm = LinearRegression()
#Fit regressions
models[0] = lm.fit(X[[variables[0]]],y)
models[1] = lm.fit(X[[variables[1]]],y)
models[2] = lm.fit(X[[variables[2]]],y)
models[3] = lm.fit(X[[variables[3]]],y)
```

When I look at "models", it seems to be storing the results only for the last regression, in all four slots.

Hope I explained well my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lm.fit()` will modify the existing instance, not create a new copy of it. Also, the `models` list will store these instances by reference, which yields the behavior you are seeing.

To solve this, you need to create a new `LogisticRegression` every time you want to fit it to a new input, not re-use the same old model.  For example:

```
models = []    # just an empty list; we will append our models to it one by one
for var in variables:
    lm = LinearRegression()  # create a new object
    lm.fit(X[[var]], y)      # fit it
    models.append(lm)        # add it to the list
```

Or, a more faithful version to your original code would be (using [`sklearn.base.clone`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.clone.html)):

```
from sklearn.base import clone  # to create a new copy of the lm object

lm = LinearRegression()
#Fit regressions
models[0] = clone(lm).fit(X[[variables[0]]],y)
models[1] = clone(lm).fit(X[[variables[1]]],y)
models[2] = clone(lm).fit(X[[variables[2]]],y)
models[3] = clone(lm).fit(X[[variables[3]]],y)
```